# How to create a jQuery listener to iterate through some markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, listener

I am looking to create a simple tooltip on an element (star rating), i want the ability to hover over each start and a different message appear.

The problem i face is the output of the star markup does not give each star a unique identifier, so i have to iterate over each collection of stars and apply a listener to each star.

Each star 1 - 5 will have the same message, e.g. star 1 = message 1, star 2 = message 2, etc.

If anyone could help, I would like some help to know how to create the listener and apply the html and message to that particular star, i want to do this with jQuery.

Here is the star markup output

```
<div class="stars">
    <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-on ui-stars-star-disabled">
        <a title="">1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-on ui-stars-star-disabled">
        <a title="">2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-on ui-stars-star-disabled">
        <a title="">3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-on ui-stars-star-disabled">
        <a title="">4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-stars-star ui-stars-star-on ui-stars-star-disabled">
        <a title="">5</a>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="rate_overall" disabled=""/>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the same event listener to each element, and check the text when it's executed (using `$(this)` which is different for different elements):

```
$(".ui-stars-star").mouseover(function() {
  var text = $(this).find("a").text(); // e.g. "1" or "2"

  // now use `text` to fetch the correct message and show it
});
```

Comment: Thanks, just so i understand, how would this find what star it is on to show the specific message?

Comment: @zizther: jQuery basically has been made in such a way that `this` refers to the element that dispatched the event. So, hovering another element makes for a different `$(this)` and thus also for a different `$(this).text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why iterate?  You have a class for your stars so a single call will work:

```
 $('.ui-stars-star')
   .on('mouseenter', function() {
     ...
   })
   .on('mouseleave', function() {
   })
```

However this it especially efficient since it registers the handler on every single element that has that class on it.  That said, it's what your current code would do, too.

The trade off is to use event delegation, using the three parameter version of `.on`:

```
 $('.ui-stars-star', document, function() { ... });
```

the downside here though is CPU efficiency - the delegated handler system in jQuery will be called for every single mouse movement on the page.

Comment: Thanks. How would it know what star it is over to show a specific message, for example, hover over star 1 should show message one, hover over star 2 show message 2, etc.

Comment: @zizther `$(this).index()` will give you the star's position (zero based) in the current list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `index()` function. ie.:

```
$('.ui-stars-star').mouseenter(function() {
    switch ($(this).index()) { ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just so i understand, how would this find what star it is on to show the specific message?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to grab an element by its text:

```
$(".ui-stars-star a:contains(1)")
$(".ui-stars-star a:contains(2)")
...so on
```